# SwiftUI Execute performDrop() on dropEntered()

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to execute performDrop() as soon as my finger is over a "droppable Area" which can be detected by using dropEntered(), without lifting the finger from the screen.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/dropdelegate

Is there any way to achieve this?

Jakob

Comment: I guess it should be possible since the `dropEntered(info: DropInfo)` Using `DropInfo` you can get the itemProviders. IMHO it would be odd for the user when the drop is performed when the user moves over his / her mouse over items as it could be even accidental / unintentional

Comment: You can certainly perform what ever _action_ you want in dropEntered(). You don't have to wait until performDrop() - E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/72384177/978300

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause.
OnDrag, onDrop is a modifier set in an item inside ForEach.

Because the action on the actual drop takes place outside of that item, the performDrop of the delegate of the item inside ForEach is not called.

Additionally, if you put onDrop in a ScrollView or an external view, you can see the call of the performDrop as normal.

Like this.

```
ScrollView {
    ForEach {
        SomeItem()
        .onDrag(...)
        .onDrop(DropDelegate)
    }
}
.onDrop(OutsideDropDelegate)
```